# RequireIf conditional validation in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my model I have the below property

```
public int? Data
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

and using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Data)` I am adding it in the view.
I have another property in the model

```
public DateTime? DateData { get; set; }
```

which I display using `@Html.FormTextBoxFor(m => m.DateData, new { id = "DateData " })`

How can I use the `RequiredIf` attribute or any other method to make the `DateData` required if the value of `Data` is not 0. So anytime the value of `Data` is not zero or null I want the `DateData` to be a required property.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge `RequiredIf` is not something that is provided by vanilla `asp.net-mvc` requiring one to use a third party / custom implementation.  It would be helpful if you could provide a link to the `RequiredIf` implementation you chose.

Comment: So apart from RequiredIf is there anything else built into MVC for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another property

```
public bool DataIsNotZero 
{
   get
   {
       return Data !=0 || Data !=null ;
   }
}
```

Then using `RequiredIf`

```
[RequiredIf("DataIsNotZero", true, ErrorMessage = "Required!!!")]
public DateTime? DateData { get; set; }
```

Please note:

As pointed out in the comments, `Required if` is not a built-in attribute. You need to download and import third party library:

[**MVC Foolproof Validation**](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/)